# Parameters are incorrect after passing from C# to unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Have been trying all day and searching various sources but can't find a solution. I am calling an imported unmanaged dll function from c#.

C++ class looks like:

```
class  MyModule
{
public:
    MYMODULEDLL_API int __cdecl Init(int);
...
```

Defined in C# like this:

```
 [DllImport("MyModule_x64.dll", EntryPoint = 
  "?Init@MyModule@@QEAAHH@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int Init(int len);
```

And calling like this:

```
Init(configFileName.Length);
```

I can see in the debugger that the proper function in the dll is being called, but the passed parameter is corrupted showing a completely different value than what was passed. This is happening for string parameters as well. Is there anyway to troubleshoot the marshalling of parameters between managed and unmanaged code?

Comment: You can't do that way... The `Init()` method has an hidden parameter containing the `MyModule *this`.

Comment: I think I see. So, do I need to make it a static class or something?

Comment: You can try: remove `__cdecl` from C++, change `CallingConvention` to `CallingConvention.ThisCall`, change signature to `public static extern int Init(IntPtr ptr, int len);`. Then pass in `ptr` the address of the `MyModule` object (or `IntPtr.Zero` for `null`)

Comment: In general don't even think of using instance class methods from C#. Probably static methods are usable (Still you'll have to fight against the name mangling)

Comment: You cannot pinvoke C++ class instance functions.  It either needs to be *static* or you must write a managed wrapper in the C++/CLI language.

Answer (score 0):

You can`t use C++ classes using DLLImport or PINVOKE, because it is suitable only for C style functions.

If you want to use C++ class in C#, you need to go with C++/CLI. You can create an unmanaged dll in native C++ and then create a simple C++/CLI wrapper which calls methods from native dll. After that you can simply add a C++/CLI managed dll to the project and use it as C# class without any DllImports and PINVOKEs. It will be a very flexible soltuion which is easy to expand. On MSDN you can find examples how to use C++/CLI.